# Calabash 'Then I scroll up' WaitError

Tags: calabash, calabash-android

In looking at Calabash's predefined [Gesture Steps](https://github.com/calabash/calabash-android/blob/master/ruby-gem/lib/calabash-android/canned_steps.md#gestures)

I do not understand why the step definition `Then I scroll up` would return the following failure:`Timeout waiting for elements: android.widget.ScrollView index:0 (Calabash::Android::WaitHelpers::WaitError)`.

What is puzzling to me is that when I run an older build of our application this scenario passes. Therefore, the error should lie in our app, but I don't understand why this would occur if this is a predefined step. When I query the view on this page I see no difference between the older and new app builds.

I appreciate any insight.

Answer (score 2):

You are probably using a relatively old version of Calabash-Android. Please upgrade to the newest version. Calabash will look for any view of the type (or descendent of)  android.widget.ScrollView, android.webkit.WebView, and android.widget.AbsListView.

If Calabash does not find any of these widgets, it will fail. You should consider using a more specific scroll command (e.g. `scroll(query, :up)`) or use panning instead (`pan(query, :down)`).

Comment: Thank you, it appears the cause is an error in the application and not with calabash.